# How to get Compass Direction using sensor_plus in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to get compass direction in my app. I am using [flutter_compass](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass) to access compass direction. But [flutter_compass](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass) is a bit slow means when I rotate my device it does not accurately give the direction of compass. That's why I want to use [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus). Because It has more popularity. But [sensors_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus) give us position x,position y and z. I don't know how to use these positions to get compass direction.

If anyone know how to get compass direction using sensors_plus then answer this question

Comment: This might be helpful :https://github.com/zesage/flutter_compass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also facing this issue. It turns out it's a problem with the `flutter_compass` plugin in the latest version. Use this package version instead of the original; it overrides stuff from the original package to fix the issues:

```
flutter_compass:
    git: https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_compass.git
```

stop and re-run the app for the fix to happen.